# Firestore ODM order by DateTime in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to order Firestore records by `DateTime` in Flutter using Cloud Firestore ODM?
In my dart model I have a field `created_at` which is of type `DateTime` and I want to order records using this field.

```
part 'item.g.dart';
class Item with Change Notifier {
     // other fields excluded for brevity

     @JsonKey(fromJson: timestampConvertFromJson)
     late DateTime createdAt;

     static DateTime timestampConvertFromJson(Timestamp timestamp) {
       return timestamp.toDate();
     }
}
```

The generated `item.g.dart` does not contain the createdAt order query. However, if I change the type to `String` or `int` the orderByCreatedAt query is generated. Why is this so? And more importantly how can I order using `DateTime`?

Comment: Are you asking for firestore to return your query ordered? or how to order this data locally?

Comment: @mikegross order the data locally as in https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore-odm/references#performing-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since type `double` clauses are still generated, I used it as a workaround to the above issue. On the server side (Firestore) I converted the `created_at` field to type `Double` since it's possible to convert a date object to a double. Then on the client side (Flutter) this would be

```
late double created_at;
```

If we generate the .g.dart file it'll contain `orderByCreated_At` which will enable me to order the records using "DateTime".

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Firestore ODM, and is currently being worked on : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/discussions/7475#discussioncomment-1901156